# Whatsapp Web + Javascript - How can I send recorded audios or voice messages programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, whatsapp, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder

I am currently developing a Google Chrome extension that offers several functionalities for customer support via WhatsApp Web. The extension caters to businesses in the e-commerce sector who often find themselves responding to repetitive queries from multiple customers throughout the day. As a result, one of the key features we aim to provide is the ability to save messages, both in text and voice formats, enabling users to send them quickly with just a single click.

Currently, the text messaging functionality is fully operational, following the outlined workflow:

1. Using a .querySelector method, I can access the message element and retrieve the text content as well as the timestamp of the message.
2. To handle data processing and storage, I establish communication with the backend. The JSON data is processed and saved in a PostgreSQL database.
3. Upon user login to the extension, the saved messages are fetched via an API and dynamically displayed above the chat area using DOM manipulation techniques.
4. By programmatically triggering a Paste event on the message input field when the user clicks on a saved message, the desired effect is achieved: the message is instantly inserted into the input field, ready to be sent with just a single click.

However, I haven't been able to replicate the behavior with audio files. I have tried recording audios using MediaRecorder in the correct extension format (ogg), but the biggest challenge is attaching them to the chat. I also attempted to simulate a drag and drop event to attach the audio, but without success.

Can someone here shed some light on this issue based on their experience or provide any insights on how to proceed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The web page may use a different mechanism to attach the audio. Try debugging its code when manually doing the task.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.